# How to start explorer.exe with QProcess when the path to the specified file contains spaces?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, explorer, qprocess

I want to start explorer and select a specific file. So I run

```
QProcess::startDetached(command);
```

with *command* set to

```
explorer.exe /select,C:\Users\....\file.txt
```

This works fine, but will fail if the path to the file contains spaces. But if I put the path in quotes

```
explorer.exe /select,"C:\Users\....\file.txt"
```

the explorer will open the documents folder and not the specified path.
Running the same string from the command line works fine.

The string is initialized with

```
command = "explorer.exe" + "/select," + "\"" + QDir::toNativeSeparators(path) + "\"";
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific about the exact syntax you are using to call `startDetached`?

Comment: Why not just use [openUrl](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl)?

Comment: @AlanBirtles, the OP wants to select the file, not open it.

Comment: @scopchanov Please see my edit.

Comment: This usage of `startDetached` is deprecated. You should separate the arguments as in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to achieve this is indeed not so intuitive, but also not impossible.

### Solution

Decompose all arguments of the command, `explorer.exe`, as separate strings, i.e. `/select`, `,`, `the_path`.

### Example

```
QProcess::startDetached("explorer.exe", QStringList{"/select", ",", "C:\\Users\\Your Username\\Desktop\\Folder With Spaces\\file.txt"});
```

Comment: Indeed it works! But I must confess, I don't understand why. Is QProcess automatically adding quotes, or is there somethin special with the comma?

Comment: @MiB_Coder, it is the way the arguments are parsed I guess.