# QtCore.QProcess.start("explorer.exe", ['/n,"C:\\Windows"']) always open Documents folder

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2

I run this command in windows10 command prompt window and it works.

```
C:\Windows>explorer.exe /n,"F:\tmp\folder1"
```

But when I run this command in pyside2 it fails.

```py
# ...
p = QtCore.QProcess()
p.start("explorer.exe", ['/n,"F:\\tmp\\folder1"'])
```

It always opens C:\Users\NAME\Documents.
why??

Comment: Individual arguments must be splitted. Change to `['/n', 'F:\\tmp\\folder1']`.

Comment: not work. I use os.system() instead.

Comment: Sorry, didn't format properly. `['/n', ',', 'F:\\tmp\\folder1']`

Comment: the second one is working, thank you!

Comment: @musicamante how to use Comment as Answer?

Comment: No need, as it's a duplicate of [How to start explorer.exe with QProcess when the path to the specified file contains spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64616788/how-to-start-explorer-exe-with-qprocess-when-the-path-to-the-specified-file-cont)